# Picasso Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, picasso

Buenas tarde, tengo un problema con la librería picasso, ya que al cambiar el imagen que viene en la url me muestra la imagen anterior y no la actual alguien, existe alguna manera para que al abrir la app la imagen se actualice ?

Comment: Agrega tu còdigo por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Tanto Picasso como Glide basan su funcion en guardar las imagenes en cache, si deseas actualizar la imagen, debes desactivar las politicas para no permitir cache:

```
    Picasso.with(this).load(urlImagen) 
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
.into(imageView);
```

Lo que realizan estas opciones es desactivar el requerir la imagen primeramente de la memoria o cache del disco.